# How Sudhosh User can login staging server without sudosh command?

Tags: command-line

When user takes access of staging server through ssh he uses the below command:

```
# sudo -u raja sudosh (user logged on in this format )
# sudo ssh xyz@server-ip-address sudosh ( login to staging server through ssh)
```

User don't want to use the sudosh command while he logins or taking ssh but he want to use `/user/bin/sudosh` shell. User wants to login as below:

```
# raja
```

and

```
# ssh xyz@server-ip-address
```

What's the solution?

Comment: What is `/user/bin/sudosh`? What *exactly* do you want to achieve? It's hard to tell from your question, as it is at the moment it seems a simple `alias`, e.g. `alias raja='sudo -u raja sudosh'` would solve the issue. Or do you want to change the user's default shell in general? That can be done with e.g. `chsh -s /user/bin/sudosh`.

Comment: user wants to use sudosh shell but when he logis to shell he is giving : sudo -u raja sudosh. instead of this he just wants to login only by his username excluding that sudo and sudosh command.

Comment: i will try with the alias option. thank u so much

Comment: Please *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments. However, this is still unclear: What is „sudosh shell“?

Comment: sudosh is a shell which allows the user as admin and the commands executed by the user is stored in a file. using sudosh-replay we can see the commands executed by user. a seperate package is there for this sudosh.

Answer (score 0):

[`sudosh` · Github](https://github.com/cloudposse/sudosh) provides detailed instructions on how to set up `sudosh` as a user's default shell:

> 1. Enable `sudo` logging. Edit `/etc/sudoers.d/sudosh`:
>
>    ```
>    Defaults log_output
>    Defaults!/usr/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
>    Defaults!/sbin/reboot !log_output
>    ```
> 2. Add this command to `/etc/shells`:
>
>    ```
>    /usr/bin/sudosh
>    ```
>
>    **Tip**: to prevent users from using other shells to
>      login, remove those shells from `/etc/shells`.
> 3. Update the user `foobar` to use the sudosh shell.
>
>    ```
>    chsh -s /usr/bin/sudosh foobar
>    echo 'foobar ALL=(foobar) ALL' > /etc/sudoers.d/sudosh-foobar
>    ```
>
>    **NOTE**: filenames in `sudoers.d` cannot contain the `.` character

An alternative (though *much* easier to bypass!) is `alias`, e.g.:

```
alias raja='sudo -u raja sudosh'
alias ssh_login='sudo ssh xyz@server-ip-address sudosh'
```